# Finding matching mathematical formulas in dataset

Tags: python

I have this kind of data set (originally comes from Excel so I past it like this in here). This is a ice hocket statistics

```
game_id | home_team_shots | home_team_saves | home_team_goals | away_team_shots | away_team_saves | away_team_goals
123 | 20 | 13 | 3 | 15 | 17 | 2
124 | 23 | 28 | 5 | 30 | 17 | 5
-----
```

There are about 15-20 rows like this depending on the exact dataset, I have about 50 of these excel.

Now I would need to find simple mathematical formulas from this data. Basically if in some column all values are less than X, equal to X or more than X. All the columns won't contain any such formula which is ok.

For example for the data above should be identified that away_team_saves == 17. And home_team_shots < 24. Of course all columns are not important so I should be able to define which columns to use.

I have mainly looking for solution in Python. I don't need an exact solution, just a push to the right direction. I am quite the beginner in Python and don't know where I should start looking.

All the help is very appreciated.

Comment: You can load the data into a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and then use boolean indexing to directly query the dataframe as in `df.loc[(df.away_team_saves == 17) & (df.home_team_shots < 24)]`. Take a look at [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that is not quite what I am looking for. I am looking for a solution that would identify these kind of consistencies in the dataset.